# How can I fix the margin of my page to sit correctly on the screen instead of snapping too low?

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

A little embarrassing, because I'm a newbie in the world of HTML and CSS specifically, but I'm practicing applying what I do know.

Basically, I've added all sorts of fun stuff to the original base code, and I guess somewhere along the way, something got messed up and now, whenever I load the page, it snaps down a little too low.

I've come to realize that this can be temporarily fixed when I make my browser smaller, and then maximize it to fit the whole screen of my desktop again, or when I zoom out and zoom back in to 100% within my browser. SOMETIMES (rarely) when I reload the page, it'll finally fit and you can see the entire page the way you're supposed to. Otherwise, just loading it regularly has it snapping down an inch or so below my toolbar, which is an issue especially since I can't add stuff to the bottom of the page without it getting eaten up by my toolbar.

I've tried messing within the code (and when it didn't have any positive result, I reverted back to the original code it's working on) but again, I'm a newbie and the code likely looks like a huge mess to anyone who actually knows what they're doing, unfortunately.

Comment: hi there, do you have a url that we could inspect? that'd make it easier to diagnose the issue. also, can you share any css that you've manipulated? for example, when you load the page, is it snapping after page load or is there a margin-top applied to the header element etc... those things make it easier for everyone to help you. and welcome!

Comment: It's sometimes hard to diagnose CSS issues without a working example.  Please copy/paste your code into this question as a snippet so it can be run here by anyone wanting to be able to help you here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FiniteLooper Hi, I'm sorry, I guess I misunderstood; is my link not working/not enough? It's over 1000 lines of code, and I'm completely unaware of what part I should be posting if I'm meant to break it up, so I figured a link would be better as I've posted it all to Github. Should I simply add the entirety of the code to my description here? I'm new here so I'm pretty website-dumb as to what's appropriate or not.

Comment: @travis_arnold The problem is occuring on is a [personal blog](https://voxxian.tumblr.com). The code is [on Github](https://github.com/voxxian/tumb.git) since I guess adding blocks here is meant for smaller code, not the entirety of it, and I'm not code-savvy enough to be able to pick out bits and pieces for review since I honestly have no idea where the issue may lie. CSS is within the code, as HTML and CSS are integrated with each other on tumblr rather than separated. It is snapping after page load, yes. Apologies for any confusion, I'm new to everything and learning still.

Comment: @voxxian open Chrome right click on the offending area in the page, and select Inspect Element, this will give you a console which will show you roughly the target area. You can then actually type in the inspector and see live updates to the css. See https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nOEw9iiopwI/maxresdefault.jpg in addition to this why don't you screenshot your page and annotate the image with some text, or a box or similar to show the issue. As others have pointed out pasting the entire template is not very helpful.